# Imacros get number of options in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, imacros

I am creating an imacros script to select a random option inside an html select element.

Like this:

```
mcr +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ... CONTENT=#"+opcionAleatoria(12)+ '\n';
```

Where **opcionAleatoria()** is a function to grab a random number:

And *total* is the total amount of options inside that select.

```
function opcionAleatoria(total) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * total) + 1;
}
```

I want to be able now to pass the *total* (amout of options in select) as a parameter to the function.

**Why?**

Two reasons:

- So I don't need to count.
- So it will work on combo boxes.

I tried passing *document.form.select_id.options.length*, but it won't work since in imacros **document** is not defined.

Do you have any ideas on how I may approach the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to modify your expression like so:

```
var total = window.document.forms[0].select_id.options.length;
```

If the suggested above way doesn't work, here's more reliable one:

```
iimPlay("CODE:TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT ... EXTRACT=TXTALL");
var total = iimGetExtract().split("[OPTION]").length;
```

(I suppose that you use 'iMacros for Firefox' and its Scripting Interface.)

Comment: You supposed right. Your option one says: "Accessing content window is not supported in multiprocess Firefox". Option 2 is a beautiful approach. Thanks.